# Plot line of average values in the current view port for high stock

Tags: average, highcharts

I am wanting to implement something that is very similar to the following chart

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/yaxis-plotlines/

```
Sorry I do not have any code
```

But I would like to create a plot line that moves with the current view port of data. So as you drag or resize the view in Highstock I would like to see an average (a single line) for the entire view port.

I have not seen any samples that do this. Can anyone point me to something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When navigator moves the extremes on x axis change. You can catch this event using this code:

```
yAxis: {
    events: {
    afterSetExtremes: function() {
        console.log(this.series[0].points);
    }
  }
}
```

`points` array contains all the points visible in view port - use them to compute the value for your plot line. Then update the chart like this (in `afterSetExtremes` event):

```
this.xAxis[0].update({plotLines: [{
 // new value here
}]});
```

---

**API references:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#update

Comment: Thanks - exactly what I wanted. Cheers